# How do I parse a standard date into GMT?

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

Can someone show me a piece of java code that parses this date:

2009-08-05

INTO THIS GMT DATE:

2009/217:00:00

====

what i have so far is:

```
       java.text.SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

       java.util.Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(new SimpleTimeZone(0, "GMT"));
       format.setCalendar(cal);
       java.util.Date date = format.parse(sdate);
```

but its not working

Comment: Note: The asker clarified that 217 is meant to represent the 217th day of the year.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the format you're looking for:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2009-08-05");
String parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/D:HH:mm").format(date);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

That's how to set it to GMT at least.  Not sure where you are getting 2009/217 from 2009-08-05

Comment: August 5th is the 217th day of the year.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    System.out.println(dateFormatGmt.format(new Date())+"");
```

This will convert your local time to GMT.