# Convert date into specific format

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am working on Java. I have a date for example: 20120328.
Year is 2012, month is 03 & day is 28.
I want to convert it into `yyyy-MM-dd` format.
I have tried it but it is not working.
How to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse a standard date into GMT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257542/how-do-i-parse-a-standard-date-into-gmt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you create the format using substring like

```
String myDate = "20120328";
String myConvertedDate = myDate.substring(0,4) + "-" + myDate.substring(5,6) + "-" + myDate.substring(7);
```

This produces the date as **2012-03-28**

Then use simple date format to convert that into date if required.

Answer (score 5):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
String ourformat = formatter.format(date.getTime());
```

If you want other than "MM/dd/yyyy" then just change the format in [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

Find some examples [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/parsedate.html).

```
  DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
  Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("01/29/02");
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/378541/java/java/Convert-date-difference-format). You will need to use the `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one for Date formatting

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
String ourformat = formatter.format(date.getTime());
```

And this one for getting TimeStamp

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Timestamp timestamp =timestamp=new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String ourformat = formatter.format(timestamp);
```